# How do I connect a LXC container to an IP alias?

Tags: lxc

I currently have 3 IP addresses going to the same server. The /etc/network/interfaces file on the host is as follows:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address XXX.XXX.132.107
    gateway XXX.XXX.132.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
    address XXX.XXX.130.21
    gateway XXX.XXX.130.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
    address XXX.XXX.132.244
    gateway XXX.XXX.132.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I would like the host to be accessible from XXX.XXX.132.107, one LXC container to be accessible from  XXX.XXX.130.21, and another LXC container accessible from the XXX.XXX.132.244. I have tried a few bridging set ups, but have been unsuccessful. Has anybody done this before? Is it even possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know of 2 ways to do what you would like.

1. Network bridging
2. IPTables Nat

We'll start out with IPTables NAT since your ifconfig output already has IP Aliases setup.

**Typical Host server**

My 'ifconfig' output shows 'eth0' as main interface with 2 IP Aliases setup, along with the LXC generated bridge interface.

```
# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:d9:66:ac
          inet addr:172.16.10.71  Bcast:172.16.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:578 (578.0 B)

eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:d9:66:ac
          inet addr:172.16.10.72  Bcast:172.16.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

eth0:2    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:d9:66:ac
          inet addr:172.16.10.73  Bcast:172.16.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

lxcbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr de:45:c9:13:2b:74
          inet addr:10.0.3.1  Bcast:10.0.3.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:508 (508.0 B)
```

The below command shows our 2 LXC containers and their IP addresses.

```
# lxc-ls -f<br>
NAME   STATE    IPV4        IPV6  AUTOSTART<br>
 -------------------------------------------<br>
test1  RUNNING  10.0.3.247  -     NO<br>
test2  RUNNING  10.0.3.124  -     NO
```

Doing an 'ifconfig' will show your 2 new interfaces created for your LXC Containers.  See 
below for mine.

```
# ifconfig
veth05DUGY Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:4c:2c:df:1d:c3
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:39 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:40 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:3706 (3.7 KB)  TX bytes:3822 (3.8 KB)

vethTUTFID Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:58:4b:19:25:3e
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:42 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:57 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:3956 (3.9 KB)  TX bytes:5580 (5.5 KB)
```

Below shows them being part of the bridge.

```
# brctl show lxcbr0
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
lxcbr0      8000.fe4c2cdf1dc3   no      veth05DUGY
                                        vethTUTFID
```

So now the actual work.  We will be using IPTables to do the forwarding.  Below is the default setup before our additions

```
# iptables -nL -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  10.0.3.0/24         !10.0.3.0/24
```

So Here we go do the following.

```
# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 172.16.10.72 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.3.247
# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 172.16.10.73 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.3.124
```

The 2 above commands add IPTables rules to forward all IP traffic from the eth0:* IP to the respective IP's on the LXC Containers.

You should see the below when verifying.

```
# iptables -nL -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DNAT       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.16.10.72         to:10.0.3.247
DNAT       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.16.10.73         to:10.0.3.124
```

So at this point you now have those IP's forwarded to the Containers.  To make this persistent you can create a /etc/iptables.rules file and from your /etc/network/interfaces file add a "post-up" for 'iptables-restore' to restore those rules at bootup.  e.g. 'post-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules' could be added under your iface line in /etc/network/interfaces.

Below is an example of network bridging.  You need to remove your IP Aliases for the below to work.  See example output below for what you should start out with.

**Host server**

```
$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:d9:66:ac
          inet addr:172.16.10.71  Bcast:172.16.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:578 (578.0 B)

lxcbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr de:45:c9:13:2b:74
          inet addr:10.0.3.1  Bcast:10.0.3.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:508 (508.0 B)
```

We won't be using the lxcbr0 interface in this case.

Create a bridge interface for use for the LXC containers.

The below command will create a 'br0' interface for use with our bridge.  You will need to add the eth0 interface to the bridge.  See that command farther down. 
** BE WARNED ** following the bellow commands will immediately brake remote connection with server and make the server not reachable via internet anymore. These instructions assume local connection.

```
# brctl addbr br0
# ip link set br0 up
# brctl addif br0 eth0
# brctl show br0<br>
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces<br>
br0     8000.080027d966ac   no      eth0
```

So the above commands add 'eth0' to br0 bridge and shows it being there.  Next we need to move the IP address from eth0 to br0.

```
# ip addr del 172.16.10.71/24 dev eth0
# ip addr add 172.16.10.71/24 dev br0
```

You should now have similar below.

```
# ifconfig
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:d9:66:ac
          inet addr:172.16.10.71  Bcast:172.16.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:77 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:6281 (6.2 KB)  TX bytes:648 (648.0 B)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:d9:66:ac
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:87 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:8183 (8.1 KB)  TX bytes:1296 (1.2 KB)
```

Next we need to edit your LXC configuration file for your 2 containers.
If your system is default, you should have the following.

```
ls -l /var/lib/lxc
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Aug 10 11:23 test1
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Aug 10 11:34 test2
```

The above output should show both of your LXC containers.  Under each directory is a file named 'config' that we need to edit.

```
# vi /var/lib/lxc/test1/config
```

Replace the line that says 'lxc.network.link = lxcbr0' with 'lxc.network.link = br0'.  Do this for both containers.

Next you need to edit both containers /etc/network/interfaces file and add the real IP address as eth0 for both.

So in my examples.
I would put the 172.16.10.72 IP in test1 configuration file such as '/var/lib/lxc/test1/rootfs/etc/network/interfaces'.  This is updating the file from the Host machine without being inside the container yet.  You of course can boot up the container and edit /etc/network/interfaces.  Either way works.

If you need any clarification or additional help just add a comment asking for help.
-Frank

Comment: You deserve a medal for this answer

Comment: After many time I also made same stuff, and got the working network on containers, but discovered inaccessibility of container from host. In other words, for example our host is `192.168.1.10` and we setup a container with `192.168.2.10`. The host will route correct to container, but can't access it direct (ping|tracerote|whatever will not work). Have you encountered with same situation?